# How to skip unavailable domain in dns serach order?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7

I am using CentOS 7. Faced such a problem. Below is a piece of the network configuration config.

DNS1=192.168.1.1
DNS2=192.168.2.1
DNS3=192.168.3.1
DOMAIN="example.com failed.local missed.local"

Let's assume the domain failed.local is down.

I'd like to ping server located in missed.local by short name. DNS client starts iterating over domains in DOMAIN="..." and gets stuck on the one that is not available and cannot go to the desired (last).

The problem is reproducible on different servers with different OS versions. Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Best practice is to not use search domains, and refer to every host using fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Michael, thank you. I completely agree with you. I just wondered if this behavior of the system could be bypassed somehow.